# If statement in Matlab error

Tags: matlab

I have the following piece of code,

```
temp = cell(0,206);
for i = 1:numel(models)
    mod = models{i};
    for j = 2:size(raw_quant,1)
        if raw_quant{j,4} == mod
            temp(end+1,:) = raw_quant(j,:);
        end
    end
end
```

when I run it, I get the error

```
"Error using ==

Matrix dimensions must agree."
```

mod is just a string, and I ensured that raw_quant{j,4} are all strings.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
L

Comment: My guess is that raw_quant{j,4} and mod are both matrices so look at them in the workspace and see if they have the same dimension. They are probably not scalars

Comment: models is a 62x1 cell of all strings. So mod is just a scalar of string that changes value each time the top loop is gone through.

Comment: Ah yes well is raw_quant{j,4} a scalar?

Comment: raw_quant is 1200x206 cell, so even if i reference a particular element with {}, it is not a scalar?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error by doing the following

```
'geoff'=='was here'
```

The **==** operator assumes that an attempt is being made to compare two equally sized arrays or matrices, and is not specific to strings or char arrays.  As you said, **models** is a 62x1 cell array.  Any element within that array is not guaranteed to be a scalar (or single character).

If you want to compare two strings, then I suggest you use the **strcmp** function

```
if strcmp(raw_quant{j,4},mod)==1
     temp(end+1,:) = raw_quant(j,:);
end
```

As well, reconsider naming your variable **mod** which is a built-in MATLAB function for modulus after division to avoid any (perhaps) future bugs in the code when you may try to use the **mod** function rather than than the **mod** variable.